# Tag-it : how to store value in hidden input?

Tags: tag-it

2 days I search, and nothing working in my case...

I use tag-it (jquery), with forced autocomplete :
user can create tags only from autocomplete list.
List is provided by ajax.
It uses li html tags. Its works well.

Actually value is stored both in visible span, and in hidden input.
I just have now to store a value in the hidden input.
Not difficult but I tried many scripts and no one works in my case...

My javascript :

```js
$("#myTags").tagit({
    tagSource: function(request, response) 
    {
        $.ajax({
            data: { term:request.term },
            type: "POST",
            url:        "ajax_tagit_autocomplete.php",
            dataType:   "json",
             success: function( data ) {
                 array = data;
                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label:item,
                        value: item
                    }
                    }));
                }
         });
        },
    tagLimit :3,
    onTagLimitExceeded: function(event, ui) {
        alert("Vous ne pouvez pas choisir plus de 3 options");
    },  
});
```

Could you help me to add statments to update hidden input value ?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

For better understand :
[The html generated by TagIt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVZrR.jpg)

Comment: I'm a poor man...   
Not able to get in same time :  
- autocomplete with Ajax query  
- tags must be in the list. No "free" tags allowed.  
- some tags can be already displayed on load  
I try since 2 days. Maybe tomorrow I discover the magic script...
... And always not enable to insert line break here !!! 2 spaces a the end of lines have no effect...